# How to get carrier name from 10 digit phone number?

Tags: android, phone-number, carrier

How to get carrier name from 10 digit phone number ?

Please note : I had success in getting carrier of my own number by telephony. But I need to get it for other phone numbers.

Comment: I think that is country specific. Often you can take your number to a new carrier. Therefore you need a query interface for resolving the carrier from the number.

Comment: This is not only country-specific, in certain countries this is not even possible because you can migrate your number from one operator to another

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to find the carrier from a phone number with accuracy. In the old days, phone numbers were assigned in “blocks” to different carriers, so all you needed to know was an area code and the 3-digit exchange (the first 3 digits after the area code) to figure out which carrier the number belonged to. But number portability means that anyone can ditch their carrier and take their phone number to a new carrier, so the old “blocks” of phone numbers apportioned to each carrier are gradually being broken up.

However, there are a few sites that claim they can give you this information (for free) and a some other sources that will tell you for a fee.

Because of number portability, these sites are not necessarily going to be accurate.

Answer (score 2):

[Authy](https://www.authy.com/) has a great API for that (besides their flagship 2-Step authentication API), but it can be a bit expensive at 3¢ per lookup.

> ```
> curl "https://api.authy.com/protected/json/phones/info?api_key=XXX&phone_number=775-461-5609&country_code=1"     
>  {
>    "message": "Phone number information as of 2014-07-02 20:40:05 +0000",
>    "type": "voip",
>    "provider": "Pinger/TextFree",
>    "ported": false,
>    "success": true
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

If you are still looking for a solution, Nexmo announced a new API called [Number Insight API](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/number-insight/request) that can get carrier information and more for a given 10 digit number. Give them a try.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get the carrier of a phone number reliably but first you need to determine if the phone number has been ported or not.  Like Iqbal says in his answer, phone numbers are typically assigned to carriers in blocks.  However, with number portability, the owner of a phone can move their phone number to a different carrier.  By looking up the Local Routing Number (LRN - see [Wikipedia - Local Routing Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Routing_Number)) you can determine if a number has been ported or not, and if so, who the current carrier is.

There are web services that provide this kind of information, one of which is PacificEast's [Line Identification Append](http://www.pacificeast.com/products/line_identification_append.aspx) which will tell you whether or not a number has been ported, who the carrier is and what type of phone it is (landline, wireless, etc.).

Disclosure: I work for PacificEast.